# How do I make an NSString that was replaced retain some of its old characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, time, replace, nsstring

My app puts a space after the ":" in case the user forgets to. Like so:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@": "];
```

This works well if they type in English. It will make "My friends are:James.." into "My friends are: James..." and this is fine.

BUT the problem I'm having is it also ads a space within a time. It will make "12:30" into "12: 30". I could make a bunch of these codes with all the number possibilities to fix, which is too much.

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@": 0" withString:@":0"];
```

What is the easier way to do this? I've tried:

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\b\\d\\d?:\\s\\d\\d\\b" withString:@"\\b\\d\\d?:\\d\\d\\b" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

But all that does is change ALL times from "hh: mm" to "bdd?:ddb" and that's it. how do I make an NSString replacement retain it's previous characters? Like how can I make it still keep the same numbers that were previously put? All I want to change is the ": " to be ":" in a time.

I've tried "if" statements with NSNotFound but it wasn't working. I wanted it that if it found a "hh:mm" format, to NOT add a space, but if it didn't, to add a space but that didn't work.

Comment: A `NSRegularExpression` could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right lines with the last version, but you need to use `NSRegularExpression`. The following should do the whole thing for you (adding spaces after colons, but not when sandwiched between double digits or already followed by a space):

```
NSString *input = @"My friends are:James, John. It's 10:30 right now.";
NSMutableString *workingString = [input mutableCopy];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(((?<!(\\b\\d\\d)):)|(:(?!(\\d\\d\\b))))(?!\\s)" options:0 error:nil];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:workingString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [workingString length]) withTemplate:@": "];
input = [workingString copy];
NSLog(@"%@", input); // Prints "My friends are: James, John. It's 10:30 right now."
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it! Also, what would be the appropriate pattern then to add a space after a " . " but not when a number is involved like 1.5.70094? I have it working by just replacing ". 0" to ".0", but this is a problem if the user wants to start a sentence with a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way..If you have either time in string or only sentence with no numbers...

```
NSCharacterSet *s = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"];

NSRange r = [input rangeOfCharacterFromSet:s];

if (r.location != NSNotFound) 
{
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@": "];
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: It works, but my app has to do with what the user types in. It won't work if they say, "It's 10:30 right now." I was thinking more along the lines of having 2 NSStrings, 1 with the space, and one without it. I tried using stringWithFormat but it didn't work.

Comment: If the string is It's 10:30 right now.Then also above works..No replacement of string is performed..!